# JavaScript - How to run these two firebase functions in sequence?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database

I want to run the below two firebase JS functions in sync since I need the values from both of these in the last `if` block to perform an operation. I have `console.log(1), (2) and (3)` to see if they are working in sync but they don't. I tried the `.then()` on the first block but that didn't work. Can someone help here? I am guessing `promise` might work here but I do not know how to implement that : (

````
let intUsersRef = db.ref('users/' + this.user_id + '/interested_in');
let waitUsersRef = db.ref('users/' + this.user_id + '/waitlist_in');

//block 1
          intUsersRef.orderByChild('project_id')
            .equalTo(id).on('value', function(snapshot){
              console.log(1);
              if(snapshot.val() == null){
                //project not in interested node
                userInterested = false;
              }else{
                userInterested = true;
              }
          });

//block 2        
          waitUsersRef.orderByChild('project_id')
            .equalTo(id).on('value', function(snapshot){
              console.log(2);
              if(snapshot.val() == null){
                //project not in waitlist node
                userWaitlisted = false;
              }else{
                userWaitlisted = true;
              }
          });
//block 3
          if(userInterested == true || userWaitlisted == true){
            console.log(3);
            //do something...
          }```
````

Comment: `in sync` ... you mean sequentially, I think that's a better term - or did you mean run both queries at the same time?

Comment: so what do you mean by "in sync" ... both at the same time or one after the other?

Comment: `on()` does not return a promise.  `on()` asynchronously adds a listener to some query results, which will be called when the query completes, and also afterward with any changes.  `once()` is also asycnhronous, but returns a promise, and queries only a single time.  I suspect you might be helped by running through the documentation to understand better.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data

Comment: same time or even sequentially... need these to run before going to the `if` block.

Answer (score 0):

```
let intUsersRef = db.ref('users/' + this.user_id + '/interested_in');
let waitUsersRef = db.ref('users/' + this.user_id + '/waitlist_in');
//get snaps intUsersRef before
const _intUsersRef = await intUsersRef.orderByChild(filter).once('value');
//when intUsersRef has return then get _waitUsersRef
const _waitUsersRef = await waitUsersRef.orderByChild(filter).once('value');

//finally compare 
if (_intUsersRef || _waitUsersRef) {
    //do something...
} s
```

Comment: @Bravo. Sr bro! i just demo

Comment: Omg, why bro! Why you down vote omg, can u see again that ask...

Answer (score 0):

Prior to the introduction of the "await" syntax in 2017, you could achieve the same result as [@anonystyick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58636996/3068190)'s answer using the following code that uses [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```
let intUsersRef = db.ref('users/' + this.user_id + '/interested_in');
let waitUsersRef = db.ref('users/' + this.user_id + '/waitlist_in');

Promise.all([
  intUsersRef.orderByChild('project_id').equalTo(id).once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.hasChildren()), // returns true if entries are found
  waitUsersRef.orderByChild('project_id').equalTo(id).once('value').then(snapshot => snapshot.hasChildren()) // returns true if entries are found
]).then((results) => {
  if(results[0] /* userInterested */ && results[1] /* userWaitlisted */ ) {
    // user is both interested and waitlisted
    // do something
  } else {
    // do something else
  }
}).catch((err) => {
  // something went wrong (bad permissions, no internet, etc.)
  // handle error
});
```

*Note: This is valid for ES6 / ECMAScript 2015*